# NSKeyedArchiver - Unrecognized selector sent to instance error

Tags: ios, swift3, nsuserdefaults, nskeyedarchiver

I'm facing `unrecognized selector sent to instance` error while using `NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData`.

I was trying to store parse the JSON output to the custom class object and store it in `NSUserDefaults` on successful login. I wanted to use these details in other controllers to make some other `POST` calls. But while saving them in my `LoginController` I'm getting this error. Can some one help in resolving this.

My Class:

```
class UserDetails : NSObject,NSCoding {


    var token:String?
    var agentId: Int?
    var userId:Int?


    //to directly get values from JSON output

    init?(user: [String: Any]) {

        guard let token = user["token"] as? String,
            let agentId = user["agent_id"] as? Int,
            let userId = user["user_id"] as? Int
        else{
            return nil
        }


                self.token = token;
                self.agentId = agentId;
                self.userId = userId;
        }

    init(pToken:String,pAgentId:Int,pUserId:Int)
    {
        token = pToken;
        agentId = pAgentId;
        userId = pUserId;
    }

    //TO SAVE IN NSUSERDEFAULTS

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder){
        self.token = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "token") as? String
        self.agentId = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "agentId") as? Int
        self.userId = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "userId") as? Int

        return self
    }

    public func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encode(token,forKey:"token")
        aCoder.encode(agentId,forKey:"agentId")
    }

}
```

And on successful login, I'm storing this details.

LoginViewController:

```
if let userDict = json["user"] as? [String:Any]
                        {
                            guard let userObject = UserDetails(user:userDict) else {
                                print("Failed to create user from dictionary")
                                return
                            } 
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {

                                self.saveUserItemToDefault(userObject: userObject);

                                self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "loginSuccessIdentifier", sender: userObject)

                            }
                        }




 func saveUserItemToDefault(userObject:UserDetails) -> Void {
            let encodedToken = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: userObject.token) //error is thrown on the first archiver call
            let encodedAgentId = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: userObject.agentId)
            let encodedUserId = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: userObject.userId)

let encodedArray:[NSData] = [encodedToken as NSData,encodedAgentId as NSData,encodedUserId as NSData]

            self.prefs.set(encodedArray, forKey: "UserDetailsItem")
            self.prefs.synchronize()
        }
```

ERROR MESSAGE:

```
2016-12-05 18:08:57.917 ABCAPP[2800:183556] -[_SwiftValue encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600000079f00
2016-12-05 18:08:57.920 ABCAPP[2800:183556] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_SwiftValue encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600000079f00'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104b5e34b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001045bf21e objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104bcdf34 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104ae3c15 ___forwarding___ + 1013
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104ae3798 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   Foundation                          0x00000001040f855c _encodeObject + 1263
    6   Foundation                          0x000000010412d29a +[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:] + 156
    7   ABCAPP                     0x0000000103fa8d4b _TFC15ABCAPP19LoginViewController21saveUserItemToDefaultfT10userObjectCS_11UserDetails_T_ + 235
    8   ABCAPP                     0x0000000103face3d _TFFFC15ABCAPP19LoginViewController10checkLoginFPs9AnyObject_T_U_FTGSqV10Foundation4Data_GSqCSo11URLResponse_GSqPs5Error___T_U_FT_T_ + 77
    9   ABCAPP                     0x0000000103f9d627 _TTRXFo___XFdCb___ + 39
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000108112980 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010813c0cd _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010811c8d6 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 406
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104b224f9 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104ae7f8d __CFRunLoopRun + 2205
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104ae7494 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
    16  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010910da6f GSEventRunModal + 161
    17  UIKit                               0x0000000104f81f34 UIApplicationMain + 159
    18  ABCAPP                     0x0000000103faff2f main + 111
    19  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010818868d start + 1
    20  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: What's the whole error message? It could help to find exactly where is the issue rather than read all your code.

Comment: @Larme added error message. Please have a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Along with inputs from `JPetric` and `Valentin Radu` I have modified the code by a little and the error is removed.

Below is my solution:

```
class UserDetails : NSObject,NSCoding {

      //var token:String? 
      var token:String!

      //var agentId: Int? 
      var agentId: Int!

      //var userId:Int? 
      var userId:Int!


    //to directly get values from JSON output

    init?(user: [String: Any]) {

        guard let token = user["token"] as? String,
            let agentId = user["agent_id"] as? Int,
            let userId = user["user_id"] as? Int
        else{
            return nil
        }


                self.token = token;
                self.agentId = agentId;
                self.userId = userId;
        }

    init(pToken:String,pAgentId:Int,pUserId:Int)
    {
        token = pToken;
        agentId = pAgentId;
        userId = pUserId;
    }

    //TO SAVE IN NSUSERDEFAULTS

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder){
        self.token = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "token") as? String
        self.agentId = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "agentId") as? Int
        self.userId = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "userId") as? Int

        return self
    }

    public func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encode(token,forKey:"token")
        aCoder.encode(agentId,forKey:"agentId")
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

The issue might be caused because you are trying to archive an optional and `Optional` doesn't have the `encodeWithCoder` method (hence the error message).

Try doing this:

```
public func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
        if let token = token {
            aCoder.encode(token,forKey:"token")
        }
        if let agentId = agentId {
            aCoder.encode(agentId,forKey:"agentId")
        }
    }
```

Comment: hi JPetric. I tried changing the code to what you mentioned above. Still same error.

Comment: Just for my curtesy, can you try to declare token and agentId as String and Int (not optionals) in the declaration of the class (var token: String instead of var token: String?) ?

Comment: I tried changing it to what you suggested(not optionals). Now it is throwing an error something like this `Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not string`  near `if let token = token { aCoder.encode(token,forKey:"token")}`

Comment: Just remove if let token = token and if let agentId = agentId from the encode metod

Comment: now the code in required init? has been throwing an error. like `self.token = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "token") as? String` should be replaced by `(aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "token") as? String)!`

Comment: Hi JPetric. I was able to solve the error just by changing the declaration from ? to ! `var token:String?` to `var token:String!`

Answer (score 3):

In addition to what @JPetric already said, which might me true, when you get this kind of exceptions, in general, the problem is that you try to archive a data type that's not representable in Objective-C. This can be an optional, a swift enum, a swift closure etc. Add a exception breakpoint to see the actual object that fails to encode and then find a way to use instead an Objective-C object.

Comment: I agree. Adding an exception breakpoint is a must (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17802662/exception-breakpoint-in-xcode)